# How can I convert a messy date column (strings) in Microsoft Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

I just got a MS Access database, one of the tables contains the column 'Enter in-service date' which is a type of Short text and users were using multiple formats for the date YYYY-MM-DD, DD-MM-YYYY, and even DD-mm. I want to convert them to one pattern (best YYYY-MM-DD) and change the column type.

Could anyone tell me where to start with that? I've seen VBA CDate function, however, I have never used it before.

Thanks

Comment: What year should append to DD-mm? Access default date structure is MM-DD-YYYY so your DD-MM-YYYY values will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

*CDate* will take them all (results are dd-mm-yyyy):

```vb
? CDate("07-2000")
01-07-2000 

? CDate("01-07")
01-07-2020 

? CDate("01-07-2000")
01-07-2000 

? CDate("2000-07-01")
01-07-2000
```

Store as *DateTime*. Then, for display, apply the format you prefer, like yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Won't Access see DD-MM-YYYY string "1/4/2020" (April 1 2020) as MM-DD-YYYY 1/4/2020 (January 4 2020)? String "15/4/2020" will output as 4/15/2020.

Comment: `CDate` is dependent on locale settings. Relying on it is very tricky and will break applications when locale settings are not what's expected.

Comment: @ErikA: Sure. But in this case they will match expectations.

Comment: @ErikA, in this case, the conversion will be done only once, I won't be relying on it for further entries.